# In Store Pickup delivery Method is not working

Tags: magento2

I Upgrade the Magento Version from 2.3 to 2.4. I integrate the "In store Pickup" Delivery Method. But this is not work .I follow the all steps Given in "https://store.magenest.com/blog/magento-in-store-pickup/"

Please Guys Let me know if anyone have idea what is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

What's missing on that article from what I can see, is the mention that you have to **have custom sources** assigned to the stock used on your website. The *Default Source* cannot be used as a pickup location for in-store pickup orders, so you have to add custom sources.

Moreover, the products have to be assigned to the sources and have to have a qty > 0 added to the sources where they should be available for pickup.

You will only be able to use the pickup in store shipping method only if you have the items assigned to the sources and only the enabled sources which have the option **Use as Pickup Location** enabled will appear there.

You should also add the physical location address for these sources when you enable this option. There is also the **Distance Priority Algorithm** to keep in mind, so GPS coordinates should be added too to the sources if you intend to use this algorithm

Please check the following resources:

- https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-in-store-delivery.html
- https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-sources-add.html
- https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-configure-distance-priority.html

Comment: Can you please help me ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/335378/77631