# How to remove unused js from home page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, performance, optimization

There are so many js files not used on home page in Magento 2. So, I want to remove it from home page. But, it's not remove still loading on home page.

Non used js example :

1. **jquery/ui-modules/datepicker.js**
2. **jquery/ui-modules/timepicker.js**
3. **moment.js**
4. **jquery/ui-modules/sortable.js**
5. **jquery/spectrum/spectrum.js**
6. **mage/calendar.js**
7. **Magento_Ui::js/lib/knockout/bindings/resizable.js**
8. **Magento_Ui::js/lib/knockout/bindings/resizable.js**

How can I remove this?

I need to remove this CSS and JS also from Google Page Speed.

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: They might not use in homepage but they use in other pages. You can check Magepack to bundle your JS file https://github.com/magesuite/magepack

Comment: How to remove that third party js from that error?

Comment: Use requirejs instead of using direct scrpts, it will help you

Comment: how did you remove them?

Answer (score 0):

you need find it in require where JS call and remove it

edit from

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
require(['jquery','datepicker','jquery/ui','domReady!'], function($,Datepicker) { 
    // Where I want to remove datepicker.js
});
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  require(['jquery','jquery/ui','domReady!'],function($) { 
    //Done. this JS will not call in your page
});
```

try it i hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score -2):

1. In your layout file you can define to remove the js that is not required..
   This blog can help you in doing this 
   [https://meetanshi.com/blog/remove-js-and-css-in-magento-2-using-layout-xml/#:~:text=Programmatic%20Solution%20to%20Remove%20JS,to%20remove%20JavaScript%20and%20CSS](https://meetanshi.com/blog/remove-js-and-css-in-magento-2-using-layout-xml/#:%7E:text=Programmatic%20Solution%20to%20Remove%20JS,to%20remove%20JavaScript%20and%20CSS).
2. This thread may help you 
   [https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/How-to-remove-js-files/td-p/48294#:~:text=To%20remove%20js%20file%20you,template%20file%20of%20that%20page](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/How-to-remove-js-files/td-p/48294#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20js%20file%20you,template%20file%20of%20that%20page).
3. Adding some code snippet so that you can understand easily 
   After we override magento 2 customer module this is the path 
   app/design/frontend/Raptor/Desktop/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
/* M241= *PROGRAMMER - Vibhore *PURPOSE - UserDashboard */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
<head>
 <title>My Account</title>
 <remove src="js/tracking.js"/> 
 <remove src="js/tracking.min.js"/>
 <remove src="css/calendar.css"/>
 <remove src="css/calendar.min.css"/>
 <remove src="mage/calendar.css"/>
 <remove src="mage/calendar.min.css"/>
 <!--<remove src="css/styles-m.css"/>-->
 <remove src="css/header-footer.css"/>
 <remove src="css/header-footer.min.css"/>
 <remove src="css/style.css"/>
 <remove src="css/style.min.css"/>
 <remove src="css/brand.css"/>
 <remove src="css/brand.min.css"/>
 <remove src="fonts/font.css"/>
 <remove src="fonts/font.min.css"/>
 <remove src="css/owl.carousel.css"/>
 <remove src="css/owl.carousel.min.css"/>
 <remove src="css/owl.theme.green.css"/>
 <remove src="css/owl.theme.green.min.css"/>
 <!--<remove src="css/styles-l.css"/>-->
 <remove src="css/print.css"/>
 <remove src="css/print.min.css"/>
```

Comment: No it's not working. I tried already. It  seems like because it's render by requirejs-config.js file.

Comment: How to remove that js?

Comment: It doesn't work