# How to move "The shipping and billing addresses are the same" checkbox to billing step in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

In my website,On one page checkout, the "My billing and shipping address are the same" section is showing after the payment method. I want it to show below the Billing address. The payment method will stay at its own place. I just want to move the checkbox into the billing address section.
How can I achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the magento default settings:
Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options
[image]

Set **Display Billing Address On** to **Payment Page**

Comment: Hey. Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/335378/77631