# Exception Message: Quote does not have Pickup Location assigned

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

I'm currently using Magento version 2.4.4 and when trying to use Paypal instant checkout - I receive an error: **Quote does not have Pickup Location assigned**

When using instant checkout and *Delivery* shipping method, all is okay.

Any insights? I've researched online and found two similar problems:

1. https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3267
2. [In Store Pickup delivery Method is not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/335374/in-store-pickup-delivery-method-is-not-working)

Unfortunately, the GitHub issue is still open over a year and a half later.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Hughes

I'm currently using Magento version 2.4.4 and when trying to use Paypal instant checkout - I receive an error: Quote does not have Pickup Location assigned

Any update on this ?